# Writing strings to a file in Java and reading them back

Tags: java, string, readfile, writefile

I have a set of strings (`String` objects) in Java and would like to write them to a file so that I can later retrieve them.

I understand that Java uses UTF-16 to store strings internally. I am worried that I might muck something up due to formatting issues unless I write and read the strings properly. I do not want to dump the String objects raw to the file as I would like to be able to open the file in a standard text editor to look at it, where each string is shown on its own line in a sensible way (assuming no string contains a line break).

Can I simply use say the `PrintWriter` class with the `println(String x)` method (assuming there are no line breaks in the strings), combined with the Scanner class's `nextLine()` method when reading them back? Would this guarantee that I get the exact same strings back?

Further, suppose the strings do contain line breaks, what is the appropriate way of writing them then? Should I filter out line breaks (replacing them with some ad-hoc escape code or similar) and use the `println` method with `PrintWriter` as above?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Have a try and you yourself will find the answer.

Comment: I believe you pretty much answered your own question, just try the code and see how it works, it's all part of being a programmer :)

Comment: I suggest you simply use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` instead of writing the strings in a human-readable format (if nobody -human- is going to read them, that is). Code would be much simpler and faster.

Comment: When you use a `Writer` or a `Reader`, what you write or read aren't chars but _bytes_; and this means you need to encode/decode.

Comment: How am I supposed to know the answer for sure by running the code? Am I supposed to try my code on all strings? :) (FYI: I'm not a programmer professionally but a computer scientist.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness I am answering my own question with the solution I eventually adopted. In retrospect the solution is very straightforward. Duh!

To write the strings I use the `BufferedWriter` class which has conventient methods for writing strings. The BufferedWriter is obtain through:

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(
             new OutputStreamWriter(
                 new FileOutputStream(filename), "UTF-8"));
```

Here I have specified the UTF-8 encoding which is supported by basically everything.

To read the strings back I use the `BufferedReader` class and make sure to use the UTF-8 encoding:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(
                 new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8"));
```